# Include from different library

Tags: c++, include

I have to create a factory method which can create objects from different libs. My directory tree looks like this:

libA/src/...
libB/src/...
libC/src/...
src/...

libA, libB, etc are compiled separated.

Let the factory class be in libA/src/Factory.h. It should create an object from libB/src/someclass.h.

If i include ../../libB/src/someclass.h in Factory.h,  then libA cant compile, because it can't find includes from someclass.h (The comiler looks for them in libA/src, but those are in libB/src) If i don't include, it doesn't know Someclass, so i can't create an instance of it.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for forward declaration: in headers where the class only needs to know the type, declare it with `class AFactory;` instead of including the whole Factory.h.

[See this tip for more info](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml).

EDIT

Having re-read your question, I find a contradiction between the fact that you want libraries to be compiled separately, and that factory of libA must know class libB. You can't compile separately then, so I would simply provide all necessary directories paths to include path.

Comment: Not the class should know the factory, the factory should know (and use too) the classes. Because the factory has to use them, the forward declaration isn't enough.

Comment: Accepted this, it works, but i looking for some other solution, because the libs can't depend on each others. Now i think i should modify a bit my structure.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this error but my example with the same directory structure and it worked fine.

```
#ifndef FACTORY_H_
#define FACTORY_H_


#include "../../libB/src/Someclass.h"


class Factory {
public:
    Factory();
    virtual ~Factory();
};

#endif /* FACTORY_H_ */
```

How do you compile them separately when there is a direct dependency? Maybe you want to use a static linked library. Please explain your intension.

Comment: In this example, there sould be something like Anotherclass.h in libB/src, and a line #include "Anotherclass.h" in Someclass.h Each lib* folder have it's own makefile, and at the end i can choose with switches what sould be linked to the final binary.

Comment: OK let's say your "make" builds "one" directory a time. The compiler would gather all included files mentioned in the Headers and build one static lib oder binary with default settings. So if you "make" your factory all included and header files will be gathered and all used implementation files also ( the whole dependency tree ). I see no problem as long as you don't have [circular dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency).
But maybe that is not what you want. Re-think the structure of your project like you wanted earlier.